# How to conditionally add props in javascript object reduce?

Tags: javascript

following functions reduces an array and maps a new object.

```js
getProps() {
  return this.items
            .reduce((map,props)=>
              ({...map, [props.name]: props.value, checked: true)})
            }), {})
}
```

What I want to achieve is that I want to conditionally add the checked property(key) if a condition is satisfied.

something like this.

```js
 getProps() {
getProps() {
  return this.items
            .reduce((map, props)=>
              ( {...map
                , [props.name]: props.value
                , (props.required) ? checked: true : null
                
                  // which means that if props.required is true 
                  // then add checked: true 
                  // else do nothing (do not add checked)
  ,)})}), {})
}
```

**EXP**

what `this` means is that if props.required is true then add the property checked with value true (so that key:value pair checked:true will be added else do nothing (means do not add the key:value pair checked:true)

**UPDATE**

It is not about conditionally assign 'true' value to the checked property.
It is about to conditionally add checked property. Note the difference here...

Comment: Your code looks somewhat correct, the only thing weird is that it's probably better to do `checked: props.required ? true : false`

Comment: No. It's not working.

Comment: I  think you didn't get my point.

Comment: It is not to conditionally assign value to checked property. It is about to conditionally add checked property. Note the difference here...

Comment: Might be easier to slap a `result.checked = this.items.some(props => props.required);` on the end.

Comment: Rather than having all in one line, split them for readability. The JS compiler (V8, or others) will do this kind of optimization for you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if` statement would do the trick:

```
getProps() {
  return this.items.reduce(
    (map, props) => {
      if (!props.checked) return map;
      return ({...map, [props.name]: props.value, checked: true });
    },
    {}
  );
}
```

or with the conditional operator:

```
getProps() {
  return this.items.reduce(
    (map, props) => props.checked
      ? map
      : ({...map, [props.name]: props.value, checked: true }),
    {}
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after something like this

```
{ [props.name]: props.value, ...(props.required && { checked: true }) }
```

And this is the equivalent using the ternary operator

```
{ [props.name]: props.value, ...(props.required ? { checked: true } : {}) }
```

Comment: wow this is a cool syntax. Can you share similar tricks? a like or something...